# IndexedDB: errors on subsequent transactions

Tags: indexeddb

I included instructions to create 4 objectStore in the database, but the program stops after creating the first.

To overcome the problem I put an `alert(...)` at the end of each creation, and, with this break, everything works without errors.

Is there a way to make everything work, without inserting these breaks?

This problem I find even if I read the number of records of 4 ObjectStore, so I always put `alert(...)` after each instruction.

I also tried to use 'onsuccess' and 'onerror', but I always had errors.

....

I finally solved using jQuery 'Promise', which is essential to solve the problems of asynchronous Javascript and IndexedDB.
This is the working code:

```
function getRecordsCountDeferred_1(tableName) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var req,objectStore;
    objectStore=db.transaction([tableName],"readonly").objectStore(tableName);

    req=objectStore.count();
    req.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
        defer.resolve({'count':result,'mess':tableName+' '+result+' records'});
    };
    req.onerror = function(event) {
       alert('Errore');     
    };
    return defer.promise(); 
}

function getRecordsCountDeferred(tableName) {
    var myPromise = getRecordsCountDeferred_1(tableName);

    $.when(myPromise).done(function(data){
        var mess=$('#info-span').html()+"&nbsp;"+tableName+": records count: "+data.count+"<br>";
        $('#info-span').html(mess);
    }).fail(function(data){
        alert("Errore");
    });
}
```

Comment: If you will put code samples and point what are you doing, and where you are facing problem then it would be useful to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is nothing to do with 4 objectStore. It must be the last database request results error and automatically abort the transaction.

If you want to continue the aborted transaction, you can call `event.preventDefault()`  on `onerror` callback.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
function infoDB(force) {
    if (!force) return;
    var count, tableName;
    var mess = 'Info sul database locale ' +
        db.name + ' - Versione ' + db.version + ':<br>';
    for (i = 0; i < db.objectStoreNames.length; i++) {
        tableName = db.objectStoreNames[i]
        count = getRecordsCount(tableName);
        mess += (i + 1) + ') ' + tableName + ' (' + count + ')<br>';
    }
    $("#info-span").html(mess);
}
function getRecordsCount(tableName) {
    var req, objectStore;
    objectStore = db.transaction([tableName], "readonly").objectStore(tableName);
    req = objectStore.count();
    count = -1;
    if (req != null) {
       alert("getRecordsCount\n" + req + " - " + tableName);
       count = req.result;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I comment out the line:
    //
    //  alert('getRecordsCount\n' + req + " - " + tableName);
    //
the function InfoDB returns nothing, with this error in the console firebug:

```
// InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
// or is no // longer, usable
//
// count=req.result;
```